# How can I make nested dom-repeat have independent loop variables?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I need to bind two nested dom-repeats. Something like:

foreach product in some_query
list all product images

So i setup a first dom-repeat which does the product query and inside I launch another query to get the images and another dom-repeat will list them. The result is that all the products listed end up with the same images.

The product names list correctly and all the queries launch correctly also but, in the end, all the image blocks are identical.

I tried with Polymer.templatize and stamp the inner template and also using some elements like iron-list but the result is always the same.

I created a "small" example here

https://jsbin.com/didijo/edit?html,js,output

How can I achieve this?

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#nesting-templates).

Comment: Why do you need to query to images. Won't your `product` object have images inside it?

Comment: It is a one to many relation, one product has many images, I don't know how many there are. In any case, it really has nothing to do with that, it is a common relation:

Company > Employees
Movie > Actors
Person > Jobs
Doctor Who actors > Companions

Comment: @BenThomas, thanks but I had already read that and I am using "as" in the jsbin code. The example in the link implies something similar to what a1626 is saying where the products object relation arrives with all the images inside it, but that is not what I need to do. I have people searching for products, I search for those with an ajax call and then I have to launch another ajax call to get the images.

I can hack the service and have it return all the information but that is not what I want to do, I want to be able to launch two nested/dependent ajax calls and loop over the results.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this issue now as I couldn't wait any longer. I got it working by creating a new web component and putting the ajax call and the output inside the component. Something like this:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <get-indexes indexes="{{indexes}}"></get-indexes>
 <template is="dom-repeat" items='[[indexes]]' as="firstlevel">
    <strong>[[firstlevel]]</strong><br>
    <get-rowdetails idx="[[firstlevel]]"></get-rowdetails>
 </template>
</template>
```

Look for me if you need help or more details.